# C error: taking address of temporary array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, compound-literals

I am passing a two-dimensional **char array** as a compound literal into a method but am receiving the error:

> error: taking address of temporary array

Does this have anything to do with the way the variable is being declared in the method declaration or is it something else?

```
void printConcatLine(char chunks[][20]) { }

printConcatLine((char*[]){ "{", "255", "}" });
```

Comment: something else. How do you call this function?

Comment: updated with the function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am passing a two-dimensional char array

No you are passing the pointer to an array of `char *` pointers.

The correct version:

```
void printConcatLine(char *chunks[]) 
{ 
    while(*chunks) 
    {
        printf("%s", *chunks++);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    printConcatLine((char*[]){ "{", "255", "}", NULL });
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sjxKpj

or

```
void printConcatLine(char chunks[][20]) 
{ 
    for(size_t index = 0; strlen(chunks[index]);index++) 
    {
        printf("%s", chunks[index]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    printConcatLine((char[][20]){ "{", "255", "}", "" });
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/76ca71

In both cases you need to pass the number of the pointers/length of the array or terminate it somehow (as in my examples). C does not have any mechanism to retrieve the length of the passed array.

Comment: I tried both of these methods and they both still produce the same error...

Comment: @McWayWeb in that case your compiler is non-conforming, try a different one

Answer (score 2):

"I am passing a two-dimensional char array" --> No. code is passing the address of  of a `char *`.

Pass a matching type

```
// printConcatLine((char*[]){ "{", "255", "}" });
printConcatLine((char[][20]){ "{", "255", "}" });
```